# Is there a way to use the "BitLocker" feature on Windows 7 Enterprise Trial version?

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I downloaded the Windows 7 Enterprise Trial version and installed it.  The final release Win 7 Ultimate has the "BitLocker" feature, just wonder if the Enterprise version can use that and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to, navigate to **Start -> Control Panel -> Security** then click **BitLocker Drive Encryption**